# Multiple browser tabs and "Back" button with PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing an application that drives execution of configuration commands in multiple routers.
Here is how it's designed:

```
  Page 1            Page 2            Page 3                                             
+--------+        +--------+        +--------+
|  data  |  PRG   |  data  |  PRG   | steps  |
| enter  |------->| review |------->| exec   |---+
|  page  |        |  page  |        | page   |   |
+--------+        +--------+        +--------+   | Ajax
                                        ^        |
                                        |        |
                                        +--------+
```

1. A user fills in the form on the first page.
2. The system fetches more data and displays it for review in another form on the second page.
3. Configuration steps are executed from the third page using Ajax requests.

I handle multiple browser tabs/windows by generating an ID through uniqid() and putting it into a hidden element in a form. The data for each tab/window is stored in `$_SESSION[$ID]`. Post-Redirect-Get is used to get rid of anoying form resubmissions.

The challenge is that when user hits "Back" button in the browser a new ID is generated. That causes `$_SESSION` and the web form to be out of sync. I was planing to use sticky forms to make the app work like a wizard but that will require the ID to stay the same for duration of tab/window existence.

Could you help me to find out how I can distinguish "Back" button click from opening a new tab?

Thank You!
PN

Comment: you can't, not reliably anyways. there's ways to detect "unload" events when leaving a page, but they're not standardized nor reliable.

Comment: OK, that helps :) since reliability matters. I probably need to think it over and come up with a better design to remove that requirement. Thank you!

Comment: unless you've got a zillion fields or very 'large' data, hidden form fields would tie data to a specific tab/window without needing server-side synching.

Comment: I don't have too many fields (at least right now). I was just trying to avoid sending data back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you number your pages according to the sequence the user will visit them and declare the session var value at the bottom of each page, you can detect where they came from (such as hitting back button).

```
page 1 = data enter page : $_SESSION['last_page'] = 1;

page 2 = data review page : $_SESSION['last_page'] = 2;

page 3 = steps exec page : $_SESSION['last_page'] = 3;
```

And compare if they came from hitting the back button with a condition like:

```
#on data enter page 1 - checking if user came from data review page 2    
if($_SESSION['last_page'] > 1){
       #USER HIT BACK BUTTON - don't re-declare session id
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. That works well when just one tab/window open. I'll explain, I could not figure out how to put it into the question without over-complicating it. Since $_SESSION is common for all browser tabs navigating in one tab would overwrite the session data for the other tab if no mechanism to handle it is provided. I came up with simplest solution of allocating unique id per "transaction" (navigation from page to page). Hitting Back button generates a new id like I just got a brand new tab open.